# compress all fastq files to fastq.gz

Tags: bash

I do have fastq files names like this:

Soil-53_R1_001.fastq
Root-29_S27_L001_R2_001.fastq
Soil-53_R2_001.fastq
Root-2_S35_L001_R1_001.fastq
Soil-54_R1_001.fastq
Root-2_S35_L001_R2_001.fastq
Soil-54_R2_001.fastq

and I want them all to compress in fastq.gz format, please suggest how I can do this with a single command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gzip *.fastq
```

will create a compressed file for any file ending in .fastq

```
gzip -r {dir}
```

will create a compressed file for any file found in {dir}.

(gzip itself never creates 1 file. You could use `tar` with the `z` option for compressing)